# using interval inside componentDidMount() in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Please, how do I use interval inside componentDidMount in react native?
I want to call receiveData in interval when componentMounts

time:date.now is there just from example, I dont know how to replace it with my function for it to work

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState({ time: Date.now() }), 1000);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}

receiveData = () => {
    this.socket.on('data', (data) =>{
        console.log("recieved data: " + data);
        this.distanceR = data;
    });

}
```

Comment: Socket listeners just need to be set up once, so i don't understand what you're trying to do with an interval. Are you trying to throttle the data coming from the socket so you only update the component every second?

Comment: Im recieving socket "data" in interval, I want to display that dynamic value in my app but I want the value to be updated not to display only first value recieved

Comment: You just need to call `setState` when you receive the `data` from the `socket` for it to update the value whenever a new value arrives. Socket listeners are `async` functions and don't need to be manually queried every second.

Comment: If you call `this.socket.on('data'` once, it will set up a listener on the socket. From then on, every time data arrives on the socket, it will run the function you pass in. You don't need an interval for this, and so i'm trying to understand why you're trying to add an interval. Your function currently doesn't do much (just a log statement and set this.distancR), so as @shadow-lad said you'll probably need to set state, but i don't see a reason for an interval.

Comment: ooooooh, thank you so much, I didnt realise that I need to call it just once and than it will do automatically